# You are lost in space paytm error (Angular and Node.js)

Tags: node.js, angular, paytm

I use Transaction Request API of paymtm. First I generate checksum hash in Node.js part and I call paytm request with following form parameter.

```
CALLBACK_URL:"https://pguat.paytm.com/paytmchecksum/paytmCallback.jsp"
CHANNEL_ID:"WEB"
CHECKSUMHASH:"TOgMQLpDzUe5MShwXJIcaZY******jvRu8XzLp4C1WRO5lzvkQydGyxQey5wrXAGqA1Lq/w8NzDLMddF34gAQP1TotT5JH9L0LOa1r**MY7g5aU="
CUST_ID:"CUST60247"
EMAIL:"chira***@gmail.com"
INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID:"Retail"
MID:"******"
MOBILE_NO:1234567890
ORDER_ID:"ORDR81517"
TXN_AMOUNT:10
WEBSITE:"WEBSTAGING"
```

and I got error like this

[image]

Comment: you posted Paytm's technical forum?

Comment: yes technical forum

Comment: any update from them?

Comment: nope no any update

Comment: Have you figured out what was the problem as I am facing same issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Rashmi Were you able to figure out the problem ? I am facing the same problem now.

Comment: Unfortunately no, switched to Quickwallet.

Comment: is the callback URL is correct?